# Using Vagrant, how can I access an apache virtual host from the host OS's web browser

Tags: apache, networking, vagrant

After installing Vagrant I've installed the Apache web server.

I've configured it to run both the default host and a virtual host. I've confirmed that the vhost is running.

From the host OS, using a browser I can access to default apache vhost by navigating to http://localhost:4567.

Given that apache vhost is called vhost2, how can I access the site from a browser on the host OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a line in your host `hosts` file and have a redirect from localhost to your virtual host.

So if you have a virtualhost configured as something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName vhost2.local
   DocumentRoot "/path/to/virtual_hosts/file"
   <Directory />
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can add the following line in your `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1    vhost2.local
```

Then you can access your virtual host at http://vhost2.local:4567/

Comment: Can you describe with a little more details where DocumentRoot should point?

Comment: I dont know how you configure your vhost but DocumentRoot should point to the directory with your server files; maybe you can add in your question your current config if its specific, I was just giving an example, the key is the ServerName and if your vhost is running from your VM, just add the line in your hosts file on your host machine

Comment: Oh, I see. It's just a normal vhost configuration. What I'm trying to do is access the apache vhost in vagrant from the browser on the operating system that is hosting vagrant. We might be talking past each other due to the overloaded term 'virtual' and 'host' used for different things in context of apache and vagrant.

Comment: yep I think I get what you want - did you add the line in your hosts' host file ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I just wasn't sure why it should work. It directs http request to the localhost. But the localhost isn't serving the domain. Rather, the vm hosted on localhost is serving it. But for the moment it only seems accessible from within the vm itself.

Comment: arg forgot to add the forwarded port in the example URL I provide, right if you dont put your forwarded port, it will go to your localhost, with the forwarded port, it should point to your VM (assuming 4567 is the forwarded port for your VM 80 port)

Comment: Yes! That does it! Thanks!